# php code for checkbox html form

Tags: php, html, forms, sendmail

this is my first time here, so please bear with me..
this is my html form :

```
<form method="post" action="contactformprocess.php">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" />
    <br />
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" value="  /><br />
    <input id=" email " name="email " type="text " value=" " /><br />
    <textarea rows="5 " id="message " name="message "  cols="20 "></textarea><br />
    <input id="submit " name="submit " value="שלחו " type="submit " ><br />
    <input id="checkbox " type="checkbox " checked="yes " value="i want
    to recive weekly updates from you "/> i want to recive weekly updates from you <br />
</form>
```

this is the php code im using :

```
<?php
    $emailSubject = '.....';
    $webMaster = 'aa@aa';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $body = <<<EOD
    <br><hr><br>
    Subject: $option<br>
    Name: $name <br>
    Phone: $phone<br>
    Email: $email <br>
    Message: $message <br>
    EOD;
    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
    $headers);
?>
```

what I am missing is the php script that validates if the checkbox was unchecked(it's set to checked) or checked and sends the info together with the other fields.
if checked send 'YES', if uncheck send 'NO' or nothing.
thanks :)

Comment: You'll soon figure it out if you use print_r($_POST)

Comment: @Pete: Better use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. You want to see the types, as well. And since he is missing the checkbox's `name`-attribute, viewing `$_POST` won't help him. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Couple issues ... your checkbox does not have a name defined, therefore, you won't get it in the post. You'll want it to look more like:

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="updates" checked="checked" value="yes"/> i want to recive weekly updates from you <br />
```

If the checkbox is not checked, it will not be included in the post, so your php could be:

```
$updates = isset($_POST['updates']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Answer (score 1):

OK here the list of mistakes i found:

1) You dont have `name` attribute for checkbox

2) `checked` attribute value is "checked". this is wrong => `checked="yes"`

3) You dont have any validation for checkbox input

Answer (score 1):

On the form, modify your checkbox code to look like this:

```
<input id="weekly_updates" name="weekly_updates" type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="yes" />I want to recive weekly updates from you!<br />
```

In your PHP code, add this:

```
$weekly_updates = ( strtolower($_POST['weekly_updates']) === 'yes' ) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

If this PHP code looks confusing, take a quick look at the PHP documentation for the Ternary Operator found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="receive_updates" />
```

PHP:

```
$receive_updates = isset($_POST['receive_updates']) ? "YES" : "NO";
```

If the user checked your checkbox, your form will contain the value `$_POST["receive_updates"] == "on"`. If the user did not check your checkbox, the request won't contain `$_POST["receive_updates"]` at all. So you can easily check with `isset` whether the checkbox has been checked by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox is not checked, the variable is simply not set.
Also, you are missing the "name" attribute in the checkbox.

So:
`$checked = (isset($_POST['checkboxname']))? 'yes' : 'no';`
would work.
Aditionally, you can add a `value='value'` to the checkbox and add to the `if` statement `&& $_POST['checkboxname'] == 'value'`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the HTML to:

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="yes" name="updates">
```

Add this code to your PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["updates"]) and $_POST["updates"]=="on") $body.="Updates: Yes <br>\n";
```